# Targeting active with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site I have 12 images and 12 switches. When a switch is pressed I am using jquery to change the filter of the image to grayscale. Right now the code I have turns every img to grayscale, I want to know how to target only the img sharing a div with the switch that was pressed.

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    $('img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
});
```

Also I would like to know how to select .switch if it's been clicked. So that when you click .switch again the color returns

Comment: It can be fixed only when you share your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the switch and img are in the same container like so:

```
<div>
  <button class="switch" type="button">Switch</button>
  <img src="image.png"/>
</div>
```

The following should work:

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
});
```

[siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: How can you answer it without knowing the HTML structure?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `I want to know how to target only the img sharing a div with the switch`

Comment: Exactly I was about to ask the same question